# How to get the index value that forms cocoon?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested, cocoon-gem

Need control **id** (or **class**) which forms [cocoon](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon).
To make custom links work only for the correct elements.
To link **price is not displayed** fill in only the field **new_price** associated with it.

And I need to get a unique value which forms [cocoon](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon).

*_promo_service_fields.html.haml*

```
.nested-fields
  %p= f.select :service_id, {}, {}, {class: "service_#{f.index}"}
  %p= f.text_field :new_price
  %p= link_to "price is not displayed", '', remote: true, class: "no-price-#{f.index}"
  %p= link_to_remove_association "Удалить", f

:coffeescript
  $(".service_#{f.index}).ajaxChosen
    # minLength: 3
    dataType: 'json'
    type: 'GET'
    url:'/admin/promo_pages/search_service.json'
    data: {'keyboard':'cat'}
```

At `f.index` I get the wrong value ([manual](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon/wiki/Manually-setting-the-index-of-a-new-element))

How can I get a unique value that forms [cocoon](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you check the code, cocoon will only replace the `f.index` if it is either surrounded with `[]` or `_`, which is how it is used in a form when addressing the nested items.

So the wiki you link to (which I did not write) just happens to work in that specific case because it the `f.index` is between the square brackets.

It is a bit unclear what you are trying to do, but there are a few alternatives:

- use the cocoon callbacks to then fix your code (e.g. assign a unique id based on the order/counter)
- use jquery selectors which allow to just address/find the nearest/closest selector